# Library to create JSON file from parsed text document

Tags: java, json

I parsed a timetable from a text document and reached the step where I have to create a JSON file from the raw data like in the sample below. Is there any library which could help me create a JSON formatted file from a raw text document?

I appreciate any help.

**Sample how it could look like:**

```
   {"route": 1
     "info": [
               {"direction": "Surrey Quays"},
               {"stops": [{"stops_name": "Lancaster Place"},
                          {"arrival_time":{
                                       "mon-fri": ["04:41", "05:41", "06:09"],
                                       "sat": [ "05:38", "06:07","06:37"]


                                           }
                           }
                        ]
   }
```

**Some sample from the text document**

```
Surrey Quays
1
Lancaster Place

mon-fri 04:41 05:41 06:09 
sat  04:41 05:41 06:09
```

**Edit:**

```
            for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<String> timeEntries = entry.getValue();    
            JSONObject timeTable = new JSONObject();
            timeTable.put("route", route);

            JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
            info.put("direction", direction);

            JSONObject stops = new JSONObject();     
            stops.put("stops_name", key);

            JSONObject arrivals = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray arrivalMoFr  = new JSONArray();

            JSONArray someArray = new JSONArray(timeEntries);
            arrivalMoFr.put( someArray);

            arrivals.put("mon-fri", arrivalMoFr);

            stops.put("arrival_time", arrivals);


            info.put("stops", stops);
            timeTable.put("info", info);

            System.out.println(timeTable.toString(3));


}
```

**Some of the result **

```
 "arrival_time": {"mon-fri": [[
    "05:04",
    "05:39",
    "19:11",
    "19:41",
    "20:11"
 ]]},
```

Comment: Is the text data already parsed?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: yes like in the text document simple. I pared it from pdf document?

Comment: I mean, do you already have a `List<Whatever>` containing a record for each entity? Or are you still up to extracting it from the text?

Comment: @Stefano: I have every thing as List<String> also `Surrey Quays` as string as well `1` and everything in it.

Comment: It would be better if the sample text file and the desired result matched, e.g. there is no "Tenison Way" in your sample text file. Also there's only "sat" in your file. Can you include a more complete example?

Comment: You can load this file into some sort of map e.g. LinkedHashMap a then convert map to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this [JSON library](https://org-json-java.googlecode.com/files/org.json-20120521.jar) from json.org . But it is just one example of all the libraries out there.

This is how you could use it: 
Let's say you already have your parser (meaning you already have a method that can read the text document and that knows what to do with the data)

```
JSONObject timeTable = new JSONObject(); // first create the "main" JSON Object
timeTable.put("route", 1);               // this first entry is just a number
JSONObject info = new JSONObject();      // now you need a second JSON OBject to put all the info in
info.put("direction", "Surrey Quays");   // first info, the direction

JSONObject stops = new JSONObject();     // now you need another Object for all the stops and stop related info
stops.put("stops_name", "Tension Way");  // like the name for the stop

JSONObject arrivals = new JSONObject();  // now all the arrivals
JSONArray arrivalMoFr = new JSONArray(); // this is the first time where an array makes sense here
arrivalMoFr.put("05:38");                // arrival time 1
arrivalMoFr.put("06:07");                // arrival time 2
arrivalMoFr.put("06:37");                //  ...
arrivals.put("mon-fri",arrivalMoFr);     // add the arrival times array as mon-fri to the arraivals object, do the same with all other arrival times (Saturday, Sunday...)
stops.put("arrival_time", arrivals);     // now add the arrival time object to your stops
info.put("stops", stops);                // and put the stops to your info
timeTable.put("info", info);             // once you added all your infos you can put the info into your timeTable

System.out.println(timeTable.toString(3));  // this is just for testing. The number 3 tells you how many whitespaces you want for text-identaion
```

And this is the output I am getting:

```
{
   "route": 1,
   "info": {
      "stops": {
         "arrival_time": {"mon-fri": [
            "05:38",
            "06:07",
            "06:37"
         ]},
         "stops_name": "Tension Way"
      },
      "direction": "Surrey Quays"
   }
}
```

I realize this is not exactly the same as in your example. But I think you get the idea. Remember, the order of the elements in a JSON Object is irrelevant. When reading the JSON, the program will read it like `json.get("stops_name");` and it does not care if the stops name are before or after the arrival times.

**ADDITION**

I saw that you put the "stops_name" and the "arrival_time"-array in separate JSON Objects. Well if you want to put them all in an object called "stops", which suggests, that you will list more than one stop, I suggest to put them together. Because the data in the JSON object has no particular order.

```
"stops": [
    { 
      "stop_name" : "Lanvester Place",
      "arrival" : {...}
    },{
      "stop_name" : "Some other Place",
      "arrival" : {...}
    }
    ...
]
```

**To your EDIT:**

your are getting double braces  `[[` because you are adding an array to your `arrivals` Object where the first entry is again an array.

so instead of doing this:

```
    JSONArray arrivalMoFr  = new JSONArray();

    JSONArray someArray = new JSONArray(timeEntries);
    arrivalMoFr.put( someArray);

    arrivals.put("mon-fri", arrivalMoFr);
```

you should do this:

```
    JSONArray arrivalMoFr  = new JSONArray(timeEntries);  // put your list of time entries directly into the arrivalMoFr array
    arrivals.put("mon-fri", arrivalMoFr);  // then add the arrivalMoFr array to the arrivals object
```

Comment: I have time `timeEntries` as list<String> is it poosibale to add it  to the `JSONArray` in this form since I am getting for ``arrivalMoFr.put("mon-fri", timeEntries);` the following `The method put(int, boolean) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>)`

Comment: You can add a complete list (ArrayList or any other kind of Collection) to a JSONArray like this: `JSONArray someArray = new JSONArray(list);`. If you already have an existing JSONArray and you simply want to add some more entries you need to give the index, where to put the additional entries: `someArray.put(3,list);`. This should add the complete list to the array, starting at index 3

Comment: Please can you take a look at my edit code? I am fycing problem since I am getting bracket `[[` at the beginening and the end of the JSOnArray.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the text file first. I sugest to create dedicated Java classes for your data. Make sure the classes reflect the structure of the desired JSON.

Once you have that you can feed youf Java object to a JSON library which turns it into JSON for free. I'm using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for that. I'm sure you will find some more candidates on SO or Google.